# Odata orderby Calculated Field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, rest

Path is a calculated field in Menu list of my sharepoint application. It concatenates two numbers into a path like below:

1/2, 1/3, 2/4, 2/2

**I want to sort my List based on this field but get the below error. How can i solve this?**

http://mysite/sites/siteone/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Menu')/items?$orderby=Path

```
{
    error: {
        code: "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException"
        message: {
            lang: "en-US"
            value: "The field 'Path' of type 'Calculated' cannot be used in the query sort expression."
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe SharePoint's REST API supports ordering or filtering on calculated columns.

The workaround is to use the ListData web service, like so:

`http://mysite/sites/siteone/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Menu?$orderby='Path'`

Comment: Are there any updates on this for Office365 sites? I still cannot filter on calculated columns using the 2013 style REST call (_api/web)

Comment: Not that I know of. Why not just use the ListData Web service?

Comment: Thats what I am now using, i.e. ListData.svc, but was hoping  if there were any updates so that I can use the _api/web and the functionality that comes with it. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use **filter** or **orderby** on **Calculated fields** in this REST method like : _api/web/getbytitile or /_api/Web/lists('{ID}') in **SharePoint 2013**

but in 2010 we can call _vti_bin/listdata.svc but we still call it in 2013 and Microsoft still supporting that way : [this article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/108828/5170)

for **filter** only way use this method in JavaScript or another instead of:

```
     var chartData = [];
    loadRequest("/_api/lists('{DDBAAAAB-AAAF-AAAD-AAAA-AAAADDDDAAAA}')/items?$orderby=order%20asc&$filter=order%20gt%200",
          function (data) {

              var listItems = data.d.results;

              for (var i = 0; i < listItems .length; i++) {
              if( Number(listItems[i].FIELDFILTER) != 0)
              {
                 ...
              }
           }
           }
```

for **orderby** only way use this method in javascript or [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760279/308578) instead :

```
function dynamicSortMultiple() {
    /*
     * save the arguments object as it will be overwritten
     * note that arguments object is an array-like object
     * consisting of the names of the properties to sort by
     */
    var props = arguments;
    return function (obj1, obj2) {
        var i = 0, result = 0, numberOfProperties = props.length;
        /* try getting a different result from 0 (equal)
         * as long as we have extra properties to compare
         */
        while(result === 0 && i < numberOfProperties) {
            result = dynamicSort(props[i])(obj1, obj2);
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```